# laravel 5.6 Eloquent : eloquent relationship model creation issue

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relation

in my controller i create an Eloquent Model Instance passign throug a relation. The model is loaded on controller's __construct, that's why is present a $this->store and not a $store.

```
public function index()
{
    if (is_null($this->store->gallery)) {
        $this->store->gallery()->create([
            'title'       => 'gallery_title,
            'description' => 'gallery_description',
        ]);
    }
    $gallery = $this->store->gallery;
    dd($gallery);
    return view('modules.galleries.index', compact('gallery'));
}
```

Simply if a store's gallery is not present yet, let's create it.

The first time i print out my dd() is ALWAYS null, if i reload the page the dd() show correctly my gallery model. 
The things is weird for me, seems like the first time the creation is done but not ready... I can work around but why this code doesn't work the first time?
Help is very appreciate.

Relationship codes: on gallery ....

```
public function store()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Store::class);
}
```

on store...

```
public function gallery()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Gallery::class);
}
```

Comment: Try `firstOrNew/firstOrCreate` function instead of.

Also provide full code please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the `$this->store->gallery()->create()` method, the original method is not hydrated with the new value, you can simply do a

`$gallery = $this->store->refresh()->gallery;`

OR

`$gallery = $this->store->load('gallery')->gallery;`

if you want to make your code cleanner you can do that in your Store Model:

```
public function addGallery($gallery){

    $this->gallery()->create($gallery);

    return $this->load('gallery')->gallery;
}
```

And that in your controller:

```
$gallery = $this->store->addGallery([
    'title'       => 'gallery_title',
    'description' => 'gallery_description',
]);
```

and voila ! You have your gallery ready to be used :)

Answer (score 0):

It's the lazy load part of Eloquent. basicly, when you tested for it with `is_null($this->store->gallery)` it sets it to that value.

when you tried to recover it again, it did not do the DB query, it just loaded the value already present (`null`).

after creation you need to force reload the relation:

```
$this->store->load('gallery');
```

or

```
unset($this->store->gallery);
```

or

```
$gallery = $this->store->gallery()->get();
```